# What is the sum of this alternating series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{4^nn!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

I need to find the sum of an alternating series correct to 4 decimal places. The series I am working with is: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{4^nn!}$$ So far I have started by setting up the inequality: $$\frac{1}{4^nn!}<.0001$$Eventually I arrived at $$n=6$$ giving the correct approximation, which is approximately equal to $$\frac{1}{2,949,120}$$ But this is not the answer WolframAlpha gets.

Comment: The sum is equal to $e^{-0.25} -1$

Comment: Actually, $n=5$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
 $$e^x=\sum_{n=\color{red}{0}}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: Why did you highlight the $0$?

Comment: @MXYMXY Probably to make it clear that the expansion of $e^x$ and OP's series start at different values of $n$?

Answer (score 4):

Your final answer is just the sixth term in the series.  You need the sum of the first six terms.
On the other hand, look again at your equation $\frac1{4^nn!}<0.0001$, which is equivalent to $4^nn!>10000$.  Find the first $n$ for which this is true.  You can ignore that $n$ and all the later ones, and find the sum of the first $n-1$ terms.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of this series is known, since it is the expansion of  $\;\mathrm e^{-x}-1\;$ for $x=\frac14$.

Comment: I don't see where the -1 comes from

Comment: It comes from the fact your series starts at $n=1$ and the series for $\mathrm e^{-x}$ starts at $n=0$.